# Return pointer to array virtual template function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual

I would like to return an array to a pointer, in a virtual function that is a member of a derived class of a template class. In details, my classes definition is:

`Sampler.h`

```
#ifndef SAMPLER_H
#define SAMPLER_H

template <class T>
class Sampler
{
      public:
             virtual T getnumber()=0;
             virtual T* simulation(int n)=0;
};

class UniformSampler:public Sampler<double>
{
      public:
              virtual double getnumber();
              virtual double* simulation(int n);
              UniformSampler(double a=0.0, double b=1.0);

      private:
              double low_bound;
              double up_bound;
};
#endif
```

The class Sampler is a template class in order to be able to derive an other sampler with vectors later. The implementation is:
`Sampler.cpp`

```
#include "Sampler.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

//Uniform
UniformSampler::UniformSampler(double a, double b)
{
    low_bound=a;
    up_bound=b;
}

double UniformSampler::getnumber()
{
       int myrand=rand();
       while((myrand==0)||(myrand==RAND_MAX)){myrand = rand(); } //We want a number in (0, RAND_MAX).

       double myuni = myrand/static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX); //Create a number in (0,1).
       return low_bound + myuni*(up_bound-low_bound);
}

double* UniformSampler::simulation(int n){
    double simulations[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        simulations[i] = this->getnumber();
    }
    return simulations;
}
```

My problem is that, when I try to call this program in the `main()`, it looks like the assignment of the pointer doesn't work. Here is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#include "Sampler.h"

int main(){
    srand(time(0));

    int n=10;
    double *unif = new double[n];
    UniformSampler uni;
    unif = uni.simulation(n);
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
      cout << "*(p + " << i << ") : ";
      cout << *(unif + i) << endl;
    }
    delete[] unif;

    return 0;

}
```

When I run it, it doesn't print any of the elements that `unif` points to. I don't understand what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

`UniformSampler::simulation` is twice wrong:

- `double simulations[n];` uses VLA extension, so not C++ standard compliant.
- you return pointer on local variable, so dangling pointer.

Solution: use `std::vector` instead.

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Sampler
{
public:
    virtual ~Sampler() = default;
    virtual T getnumber() = 0;
    virtual std::vector<T> simulation(int n) = 0;
};

class UniformSampler:public Sampler<double>
{
public:
    explicit UniformSampler(double a=0.0, double b=1.0);

    double getnumber() overrid;
    std::vector<double> simulation(int n) override
    {
        std::vector<double> res(n);
        for (auto& val : res){
            res = getnumber();
        }
        return res;
    }
private:
    double low_bound;
    double up_bound;
};

int main(){
    srand(time(0));

    constexpr int n = 10;
    UniformSampler uni;
    auto unif = uni.simulation(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        std::cout << "p[" << i << "]: " << unif[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The idea was not to use `std::vector` (since I am learning c++, I want to start with the basics), so I will instead pass the pointer as a parameter of the function.

Comment: If you cannot use `std::vector`, create your own simplified version once. You can test it independently than the rest of the code and vice versa.